# Postgres Kubernetes Helm chart fails when istio enabled

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, istio, azure-aks

I have installed istio in my aks cluster and enabled it to a namespace called database as below.

```
kubectl label namespace database istio-injection=enabled
```

I'm going to install helm3 posgress database into database namespace.

```
helm install pg-db bitnami/postgresql-ha --version=2.0.1 -n database
```

few seconds database starting to fails because the database pod is not considered healthy.

when I disable adding sidecar into database as below it doesn't restart. How can I run this helm chart without disabling sidecar

```
podAnnotations:
    sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
```

listing pods
[image: pods]

pg-db-postgresql-ha-postgresql-1 logs
[image: pg-db-postgresql-ha-postgresql-1 logs]

pg-db-postgresql-ha-pgpool-5475f499b8-7z4ph logs
[image: pg-db-postgresql-ha-pgpool-5475f499b8-7z4ph logs]

Comment: could you share the error for the database pod not starting when the `istio-injection` flag is true ? Are you getting probe timeout ?

Comment: @djsly updated logs in question

Comment: Hi, Can You also add kubernetes and istio versions? As alternative You can disable istio-injection in the database and then add it with `ServiceEntry`.

Comment: @PiotrMalec kubernetes version: 1.15.10, istio version: 1.6

Comment: you seem to have a DNS issue when using itsio. and headless service. this seems to say that it should be working. but has Piotr is saying, SErivceEntry might help here https://discuss.istio.io/t/istio-1-5-and-headless-services/5910/2

Comment: If the alternative solution is acceptable You can check my SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62165493/why-i-am-getting-connection-refused-by-istio-side-car-injector/62216798#62216798) where i explain how to use `ServiceEntry` to add Database to istio mesh.