# Why i am getting connection refused by istio side car injector?

Tags: kubernetes, istio

i have created PostgreSQL cluster using crunchydata pgo operator in a namespace with istio-injection enabled.but now getting api server connection refused.

```
level=error msg="Get https://100.xx.xx.xx:443/apis/batch/v1/namespaces/project/jobs?labelSelector=pg-cluster%3Dmilkr7%2Cpgdump%3Dtrue: dial tcp 100.xx.xx.xx:443: connect: connection refused".
```

*api server log*:

```
W0603 03:04:21.373083  1 dispatcher.go:180] Failed calling webhook, failing closed sidecar-injector.istio.io: failed calling webhook "sidecar-injector.istio.io": Post https://istio-sidecar-injector.istio-system.svc:443/inject?timeout=30s: dial tcp 100.65.xx.xx:443: connect: connection refused
I0603 03:18:59.654964 1 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 172.20.xx.xx:44638: remote error: tls: bad certificate
```

Comment: Injecting Databases with istio is really complicated. In istio You can set up Database without injecting and then add it to Istio registry using `ServiceEntry` object so it would be able to communicate with the rest of istio services. Would You be interested in this alternative approach?

Comment: @Piotr Malec, yes i am interested in this approach and i am trying it. It would be great to have a good documentation on this approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add Your Database to istio service mesh You can use [`ServiceEntry`](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/) object.

> `ServiceEntry` enables adding additional entries into Istio’s internal service registry, so that auto-discovered services in the mesh can access/route to these manually specified services. A service entry describes the properties of a service (DNS name, VIPs, ports, protocols, endpoints). These services could be external to the mesh (e.g., web APIs) or mesh-internal services that are not part of the platform’s service registry (e.g., a set of VMs talking to services in Kubernetes). In addition, the endpoints of a service entry can also be dynamically selected by using the `workloadSelector` field. These endpoints can be VM workloads declared using the `WorkloadEntry` object or Kubernetes pods. The ability to select both pods and VMs under a single service allows for migration of services from VMs to Kubernetes without having to change the existing DNS names associated with the services.

Example of `ServiceEntry` yaml manifest for database:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: ServiceEntry
metadata:
  name: db-service
  namespace: databasens
spec:
  exportTo:
    - "."
  hosts:
    - db-service.xxx.com
  ports:
    - number: 5443
      name: tcp
      protocol: tcp
  resolution: DNS
  location: MESH_EXTERNAL
```

If You have mTLS enforcement enabled You will also need `DestinationRule` that will define how to communicate with the external service.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: DestinationRule
metadata:
  name: mtls-db-service
spec:
  host: db-service.xxx.com
  trafficPolicy:
    tls:
      mode: MUTUAL
      clientCertificate: /etc/certs/myclientcert.pem
      privateKey: /etc/certs/client_private_key.pem
      caCertificates: /etc/certs/rootcacerts.pem
```

For more information and more examples visit istio [documentation](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/service-entry/) page for `ServiceEntry`.

Hope it helps.